# Adding servlet with urlPatterns = {"/"} makes css and other local files problematic

Tags: java, servlets

I am New to java servlet and hence when I added a servlet with `urlPatterns = {"/"}`, the jsp files which were loading local css and js files correctly, just went horribly wrong and couldn't find the resources. When I removed that servlet, it started working fine again. Can someone please explain why is this happening ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your servlet is handling their requests.

Comment: @SLaks so what's the way out ?

Comment: Don't map a servlet to /, since that means that the servlet is supposed to handle **all** requests, and apparently you don't want that.